How to export secret variables inside Azure DevOps Release during Bash script from file execution
I have a script that change variables in files to expected values.
It works if I use inline option of bash script. It crush during execution of filePath.
export VersionTag=${BUILD_BUILDNUMBER}

export $(xargs <${VALUESMAIN})
export $(xargs <${VALUES})

export Auth_Azure_Client_ID=${Auth_Azure_Client_ID}
export Auth_Azure_Shared_Secret=${Auth_Azure_Shared_Secret}


env

cd ../../helm/

envsubst < -core-api-values.yaml >> coreapi.yaml

First 3 lines are the exposed variables from Azure DevOps variable group.
export Auth_Azure_Client_ID=${Auth_Azure_Client_ID}
export Auth_Azure_Shared_Secret=${Auth_Azure_Shared_Secret}

they are secret variables in the same group.
If I use the inline option everything works fine:

But if I want to use script from file:

The script ends without exporting secret values:
export Auth_Azure_Client_ID=${Auth_Azure_Client_ID}
export Auth_Azure_Shared_Secret=${Auth_Azure_Shared_Secret}

I can't see them with execution of env or set
After trying to export they are just empty

When you use the variable group, you need to follow the answer shared by Shamrai Aleksander to manually map the secret to env variable. But as mentioned in your comment, if you use the key vault to save the secret, we can use script or extension to directly read the value in bash file. In this case, we can skip the environment variable mapping step. I have shared the bash script about how to get the key vault secret value  in my answer , you can refer it too.

Add your secret variable as an environment variable on your task: Use a secret variable in the UI


I have more than 20 secrets. I am looking for automated solution.
Also there is an example for Inline option
I am using filePath and Bash

@PiotrŁączykowski as mentioned in the link shared by Shamrai: Unlike a normal variable, secret aren't automatically decrypted into environment variables for scripts. You need to explicitly map secret variables.

@PiotrŁączykowski I am afraid that there is out-of-box method can map the secret to env variable automatically. AND if you are using bash and filepath, you still can find the Environment variables option and manually map the secret variable.

Hmmm what if I will use Azure Key Vault?

@PiotrŁączykowski will be the same. That will work only for the inline approach. As a workaround, you may add reading akv secrets in your script.

As the answer shared by Shamrai Aleksander, if you use the variable group to save the secret variables, you need to manually map the secret variable in Bash task -> Environment Variables.

There is no out-of-box method can map the secret variable in variable group to env variable automatically.

what if I will use Azure Key Vault?

When you use Azure Key Vault, you can use the following two methods to read the secret value and use it in bash file.
Method1: We can use Azure CLI: az keyvault secret show to read the key vault secret value and export to variable in bash file.
For example: .sh file
....

export Auth_Azure_Client_ID=$(az keyvault secret show --name secretname --vault-name keyvaultname --query value -o tsv)
export Auth_Azure_Shared_Secret=$(az keyvault secret show --name secretname --vault-name keyvaultname --query value -o tsv)

.....

Then we need to use Azure CLI task to run the bash file to provide the authentication info.
For example:
- task: AzureCLI@2
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'serviceconntionname'
    scriptType: 'bash'
    scriptLocation: 'scriptPath'
    scriptPath: 'test.sh'

Method2: We can use the Read Secrets from Key Vault task extension to read the secrets in azure key vault. And  the task will store them in a regular variables (and not in secret variables like the Microsoft built-in task).
Note:  This extension task only can be used in Windows system.
